# Updating a single value in a reord not working with a button?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a database of a checklist, and am displaying the database in tables, one table for items on the list that are complete and one for those that arent. I have a button on each row of the uncomplete table that when I click I want it to update the database and send the record to the completed table.

```
        <div class="table_undone"> 
<!--Display undone checklist items-->
    <h2>STILL TO DO</h2>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM checklist WHERE done = '' ORDER BY id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            //display the header of the table
            echo "<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ITEM</th>
                        <th>DUE DATE</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //display the contents of the table
                echo "<tr>
                        <td>".$row['item']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['due_date']."</td>   
                        <td>
                            <form id='complete_item' name='complete_item' action='index.php' method='get'>
                                <button class='button' type='button' name='complete' value=".row['id'].">COMPLETE</button>
                            </form>
                      </tr>";
            } 
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 RESULTS";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

I have this to display the table.

```
    <?php
//once an item is complete send it to the completed table using the complete button
$id=$_POST['id'];
$item=$_POST['item'];
$due_date=$_POST['due_date'];
$done=$_POST['done'];
if(isset($_POST['complete'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE checklist SET done = 'y' WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if ($sql) {
        echo "Success in updating the record!";
    } else {
        echo "Failure in updating the record!";
    }
}
```

?>

and this to update the record, changing the done value to "y", which then would dsplay it in the correct table, but this isnt working?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What part is not working? The update command works fine?

Comment: When i press the button nothing happens for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change viewing code to following... Bcoz button no need.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //display the contents of the table
                echo "<tr>
                        <td>".$row['item']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['due_date']."</td>   
                        <td><a href='update.php?id=".$row['id']."'>complete</a></td>
                      </tr>";
            }
```

And your **update.php** should be like (Your same code But small changes),

```
<?php
//once an item is complete send it to the completed table using the complete button

   // make sure the $conn is exist

    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE checklist SET done = 'y' WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if ($sql) {
        echo "Success in updating the record!";
    } else {
        echo "Failure in updating the record!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you! that worked, is there anyway for it to automatically go back to the page again after?

Comment: put this line at the point where you want to redirect, `header("location: yourpage.php");`

Comment: @oliverthomas Good luck! Cheers... Mark this answer if this really solved your problem.

Comment: Thank yoiu very much for the help this is brilliant!